Gradle Protobuf plugin builds error with new version of Gradle
I have a Kotlin project with a build.gradle.kts file  which has some protobuf task. It has Gradle version 7.5 and com.google.protobuf version 0.8.14. I am trying to upgrade the Grade from 7.5 to 8.10.
However I got the following error when building the project. Anybody see this before?
* What went wrong:
'org.gradle.api.NamedDomainObjectContainer org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.NamedDomainObjectContainerExtensionsKt.invoke(org.gradle.api.NamedDomainObjectContainer, kotlin.jvm.functions.Function1)'

Here is the relevant snippet which the protobuf related configuration
    import com.google.protobuf.gradle.generateProtoTasks
    import com.google.protobuf.gradle.id 
    import com.google.protobuf.gradle.plugins
    import com.google.protobuf.gradle.protobuf
    import com.google.protobuf.gradle.protoc

    protobuf {
        protoc {
            artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.19.2"
        }
        plugins {
            id("grpc") {
                artifact = "io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.46.0"
            }
            id("grpckt") {
                artifact = "io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-kotlin:1.3.0:jdk8@jar"
            }
        }
        generateProtoTasks {
            all().forEach { task ->
                task.plugins {
                    id("grpc")
                    id("grpckt")
                }
            }
        }
    }
   

